# How to convert point fraction to vulgar fraction?

Tags: perl

How to convert point fraction to vulgar fraction in perl ? Any examples/modules ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also [Number::Fraction](http://search.cpan.org/~davecross/Number-Fraction-1.13/lib/Number/Fraction.pm) in addition to Math::Fraction that Borodin mentioned. Both beautiful examples of overloading in perl. If you want to look more into it and perhaps implement something like it yourself, there's [a good introduction to overloading at perl.com](http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/07/22/overloading.html)

Comment: Number::Fraction doesn't do what the OP wanted. It'll convert from rational numbers to real numbers, but not the other way round. And thanks for the reminder of that article on overloading - I'd forgotten that I wrote it :)

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [Math::Fraction](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aFraction).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Fraction;

my $frac = frac(.666);
print $frac * frac(3/4);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1/2
```